# Loading markers at intervals

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, setinterval

In my project I have a google map, and I need to get markers on my map from database.
I have simple code like in example:

```
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () { 
         getmarkers(map);

        }); 
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

This code works well, but it has one lack - it loads new markers only if user moves map.
But I need to load markers also if user is just sitting in front of computer and look on a map, not moving it.

I think the best way to do this is to use `setInterval(getmarkers(map), 3000)` but if I use it except where that function `google.maps.event.addListener(...` it can't find map. Are there any ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are 2 issues,

1. `setInterval` expects the first argument to be a function(but it isn't, it's a function-call which will be executed immediately). Use a anonymous function to execute the statement:

   ```
   setInterval(function(){getmarkers(map);}, 3000);
   ```
2. place the `setInterval`-call at the end of `initialize` to be sure that map is defined.

Comment: hmm.. it's a good idea, and it's help me to solve the problem, but, now there is another problem. First call of the `getmarkers` function does not occur immediately, and if I set big interval, for example 30 seconds, user will see blank map for this time.
I tried to do this:
`initialize(){.......... getmarkers(map), setInterval(function(){getmarkers(map);}, 3000);` Getmarkers function can't find map if i call it before setinterval.

Comment: I solve it like this:
setTimeout(function(){getMarkers(map);setInterval(function(){getMarkers(map);}, 30000); }, 3000);

Comment: Your first attempt should work too. What is getMarker doing, does it somehow try to access the bounds of the map?

Comment: Yes, it gives error when it try to access the bounds.